# ws4py.websocket: Closing connection from client long delay

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, ws4py

I created a secure WebSocket server using the ws4py.websocket package.

A javascript client connects to this Websocket and sends some JSON messages to it.

Now when my JS client closes the connection (`function disconnect`), it takes about 30 secondes before the server's `closed` function gets called

Here's the code:

**Server**

```
class ControlWebSocket(WebSocket):

    def opened(self):
        print("Client connected")

    def closed(self, code, reason=None):
        print("Connection closed [%d]" % (code))

    def received_message(self, m):
        #some business logic using 'm'
server = make_server('', 8999, server_class=WSGIServer, handler_class=WebSocketWSGIRequestHandler, app=WebSocketWSGIApplication(handler_cls=ControlWebSocket))
server.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (server.socket, certfile='./cert.pem', keyfile='key.pem', server_side=True)
server.initialize_websockets_manager()
server.serve_forever()
```

**Client**

```
ws = new WebSocket("wss://192.168.42.1:8999/");

ws.onopen = function() {
    console.log("Connected to WebSocket server");
};

ws.onmessage = function(e) {
    //some business logic using e
};

ws.onclose = function() {
    console.log("Disconnected from WebSocketServer");
};

function disconnect() {
    console.log("Disconnecting from WebSocketServer");
    ws.close();
}
```

Any clues on why this is so long to close the connection ? Are there any ways to terminate the connection faster ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This your client side issue. If you look in the `ws` module. At the top you have

```
const closeTimeout = 30 * 1000; // Allow 30 seconds to terminate the connection cleanly.
```

And then you have below code

```
  if (!this._finalized) {
    if (this._closeFrameReceived) this._socket.end();

    //
    // Ensure that the connection is cleaned up even when the closing
    // handshake fails.
    //
    this._closeTimer = setTimeout(this._finalize, closeTimeout, true);
  }
```

Which is to ensure the connection doesn't close before 30 second and gives each party enough time to cleanup the connection. This time is a `const` and not `configurable` as such. But if you want the termination to happen instantly you can add a `ws.finalize()` after `ws.close()` and it would disconnect immediately

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
let ws = new WebSocket("wss://127.0.0.1:8999/", {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
});

ws.onopen = function() {
    console.log("Connected to WebSocket server");
};

ws.onmessage = function(e) {
    //some business logic using e
};

ws.onclose = function() {
    console.log("Disconnected from WebSocketServer");
};

function disconnect() {
    console.log("Disconnecting from WebSocketServer");
    ws.close();
    ws.finalize();
}

setTimeout(disconnect, 100)
```

**Edit-1**

After digging deeper it seems the `ws4py` has some stuff not in accordance to [rfc6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.3).

When you do a close from NodeJS, it sends a close frame of `\x88\x80` which indicates that connection should be closed and a close frame should be sent. The file `ws4py/streaming.py` has some issues where it doesn't respond to this frame properly. It basically expects more data to be read and gets stuck waiting for the same. This cause the connection to be closed from the client side with the default 30 second timeout.

So this is a bug in the python library which you are using. I created a client using NodeJS `WebSocket.server` it closed properly.

Why don't you use the Server in NodeJS itself? There is a great example for doing the same at below link

https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/examples/ssl.js

code here for reference

```
'use strict';

const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const WebSocket = require('..');

const server = https.createServer({
  cert: fs.readFileSync('../test/fixtures/certificate.pem'),
  key: fs.readFileSync('../test/fixtures/key.pem')
});

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

wss.on('connection', function connection (ws) {
  ws.on('message', function message (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  });
});

server.listen(function listening () {
  //
  // If the `rejectUnauthorized` option is not `false`, the server certificate
  // is verified against a list of well-known CAs. An 'error' event is emitted
  // if verification fails.
  //
  // The certificate used in this example is self-signed so `rejectUnauthorized`
  // is set to `false`.
  //
  const ws = new WebSocket(`wss://localhost:${server.address().port}`, {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  });

  ws.on('open', function open () {
    ws.send('All glory to WebSockets!');
  });
});
```

Comment: This even more makes me think that it's a server-side issue: client sends the 'close' frame and the server should also respond with a close frame, terminating the connection without delay. I used another websocket python lib which worked fine and I have this problem since I switched to ws4py (for ssl support)

Comment: I can't use Node as this websocket controls a quadcopter and all my codebase uses python (and I don't want to layer a Node server over it). it's a shame that ws4py doesn't send a proper close frame. I'm either gonna handle this client-side or try another python WS lib. Ty very much for your explanations